# A simple one way repeated measures anova did not give any results

Tags: r, regression, anova, repeated-measures

I have a very simple sample dataset. There are four trait values from two animals (I know the sample size is very small. For each animal, one side of the body was treated with drug, and the other was not. Then trait values from both sides of the body of the two animals were measured. Body size was used as a covariate.So treatment can be paired with control in this dataset. I hope to examine the impact of treatment on trait values.

```
   trait   body        Treatment ID
 2217.6758 624083         N      a      
  481.8359 396332         N      b      
 3883.1055 636011         Y      a      
  777.7344 377092         Y      b 

 

m=aov(trait~body+treatment+Error(ID/(treatment),df)
```

However, no F or p values were calculated. Anything wrong with it?

Comment: Could you show your full code? The `aov` function usually produces the info you seek.

Comment: It seems to me the body values should be the same for each related ID.  That is, if ID=a is one animal, shouldn't that animal have the same body.

Comment: Hi@GreggH, Sorry for the confusion. The 'body' value is actually a measurement of a certain body part, which is present in both sides where I measured the trait value, so they are slightly different.

Answer (score 1):

Your sample size for a repeated measure would be ok...if you only had the treatment factor.  This would give you 1 degree of freedom (the smallest possible).  However, if you include the covariate, you have no degrees of freedom left, and you will get a perfectly fitting solution (thus no error to assess statistical significance).

Comment: Hi, Yes, when I remove the covariate, it did produce the usual stuff...

Answer (score 1):

Your dataset is too small for the model. The model is saturated and a perfect fit.

I added 4 lines to the data (making up numbers) and then summary(m) output the usual stuff.